# IETF syslog input to fluentd

Tags: syslog, fluentd

Is there any way to support IETF / RFC 5424 syslog messages with fluentd? My application has no disk, so tailing a file is not an option. The system already outputs standard syslog messages, but it looks like fluentd's syslog plugin is not, by default, able to parse the RFC 5424 message format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Fluentd maintainer here.

You are correct: in the past, Fluentd only supported a "default" syslog message via in_syslog. Hopefully in the next version, we have in_tcp and in_udp which accept arbitrary input format, including RFC 5424 syslog format. [Here is a pull request for it](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/pull/368)